# PHP merging two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to merge two arrays with array_merge(), but I am receiving the following warning:

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array on line 41

Here is the code:

```
$travel = array("Automobile", "Jet", "Ferry", "Subway");

echo "<ul>";

foreach ($travel as $t)
{
    echo "<li>$t</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
?>

<h4>Add more options (comma separated)</h4>
<form method="post" action="index2.php">
<input type="text" name="added" />
<?php
foreach ($travel as $t){
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"travel[]\" value=\"$t\" />\n";
 }
 ?>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" /> 
 </form>
 <?php
$travel = $_POST["travel"];
  $added = explode(",", $_POST["added"]);

$travel = array_merge($travel, $added);

print_r ($travel);


?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning `$_POST["travel"]`, which is not an array but a string, to `$travel`. Turn it into an array first.

Comment: hm.. actually `$_POST["travel"]` is an array, if you're using `name="travel[]"`

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing `$_POST["travel"]` but it's not defined if you didn't submit the form. You need to check if it's a post request:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["travel"])){
    $travel = $_POST["travel"];
    $added = explode(",", $_POST["added"]);

    $travel = array_merge($travel, $added);
}

print_r ($travel);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is an array, `$_POST['travel']` however is just an element unless its originating from a multiselect element.